# Why is my spacemacs stuck on a white colour?

Tags: emacs, themes, spacemacs

I have just recently installed spacemacs and activated a few layers. I installed themes-megapack and after emacs restart, the screen is now stuck on a white theme.

[image]

I have tried to change the themes the normal way as well with no success. I have tried to reinstall spacemacs altogether but its the same.

My .spacemacs file is [here](https://gist.github.com/iprateekk/e294e2937b654af2b618726182a87f58)

Comment: have you tried `SPC T s`, which should give you a helm buffer to select a theme?

Comment: Yes I have. Sadly it did not work. It seems like some custom variables are overriding my theme.

Comment: what is your emacs version, I think spacemacs needs a relatively new version, and did you check `develop` vs `master` branch of spacemacs?

Comment: something very similar to your screen shot just happened to me, it was while editing an elisp buffer and during the parsing of semantic mode. I fixed it by changing the theme to something else and back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out! At the bottom of my .spacemacs file custom-set-faces block of code that was overwriting my themes. I changed it to the following and it worked:

```
(custom-set-faces
 '(default ((t (:background nil)))))
)
```